# Does Task Scheduler still run tasks even if the PC is unresponsive?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a PC that's prone to freezing, no blue screen or any errors, just ends up being unresponsive. The only fix I can think of is just restarting the PC. I created a new scheduled task which will do a force restart every weekend. My question is that when the PC is frozen, is task scheduler able to still perform my restart scheduled task? The system in question is running Windows 10 Home and is a Dell OptiPlex 3020.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. Task Scheduler is just another process running on the same OS. So if the OS as a whole is frozen, the Task Scheduler service is frozen as well.

(Though it *may* continue to work if it's actually just the display (GPU) that's frozen but the processes are intact, e.g. if you can still hear music playing without interruptions or if the host still responds to `ping` from another system.)

Answer (score 0):

This question can't be answered without knowing the cause of the
freeze. If the cause relates only to human interface, then the
Task Scheduler is not affected.

In most cases the cause only relates to the graphics card driver,
so is relatively harmless.

You may check this by entering the following key combination when
it happens:
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

This key combination refreshes your graphics driver. The screen will
flash for a second or two, and if all is back to normal then the
problem is indeed a bug in the graphics driver.
This can be the workaround for the problem until a better solution
is found, such as a more recent display driver.

Comment: I will try this key combination when another PC has the same issue. Though it's most likely not a graphics card driver issue since on TeamViewer, the PC will be showing as offline. Would you happen to know of a way to find the cause of a freeze? I tried using Event Viewer and looking at the System portion but couldn't find anything that tells me the cause of a freeze.

Comment: The common causes are the display and the network. Event Viewer is good, but don't try to guess in which section to look. Look also for `.dmp` files in folders `C:\Windows\Minidump` and `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\CrashDumps`.